# ConnectionString property not printing connection string

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, azure-analysis-services

I am trying to get the connection string of a database datasource with the following script:

```
   $Analysis_Server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server  
   $Analysis_Server.connect("$server") 

   $database = $Analysis_Server.Databases[7]
   $c = $database.DataSources[0].ConnectionString
   $c
```

nothing is outputting.

I have tried debugging like so:

```
$Analysis_Server.Databases
```

this prints out all databases on the server

if i index it `$Analysis_Server.Databases[]`, it prints whatever database is indexed (so in my case, 7, prints database8)

clearly the Database property is working.

-------------**UPDATE**:--------------

here is how the Databases look in the server

[image: server1_Databses]

here is what each of the following lines does:

```
   $Analysis_Server.Databases
```

this prints out

[image: Databses]

One thing one can notice is for some reason they are printed out not in order of how they are on the analysis server as in the picture...I dont know why that is the case

this is what this command prints out:

```
Analysis_Server.Databases[0]
```

[image: Database8]

Now since index 0 worked, we should be able to index `[1], [2]`, etc...

so the following

```
Analysis_Server.Databases[1] 
Analysis_Server.Databases[2]
```

prints:

[image: databases1 and 3]

Now unto the connection string:

```
$Analysis_Server.Databases[0].DataSources[0].ConnectionString
```

that prints out:

> Connection Timeout=60;User Id=someID;Data Source=10.10.10.10;Persist Security Info=True

its appears to be the connection string for Database8

cool, so then we should be able to do this as well:

```
$Analysis_Server.Databases[1].DataSources[0].ConnectionString
```

However, nothing prints! the only index that seems to print is with `Databases[0]`

This is what `$Analysis_Server.Databases[0].DataSources[0]` prints:

[image: DataSources0]

we should be able to do the same for all databases

`$Analysis_Server.Databases[1].DataSources[0]`

`$Analysis_Server.Databases[2].DataSources[0]`
etc..

but nothing gets printed!

Comment: you should add the info that the connectionstring prints fine on other dbs on that server, or is that not the case anymore? also add some sql tags to get some sql people to look at this

Comment: @Paul, ya no matter what, it's only printing with indexes [0] only. Any other index ...nothing. it doesnt make sense at all. Not only that, but when index is 0, its somehow printing the last database (i.e. database8), instead of database 1, since logically 0 is the first index! This looks broken to me/bug. I'll take your suggestion and add more tags ...

Comment: Looks to be this class... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.databasecollection?view=sqlserver-2016   Can you provide some of the data that you get?

Comment: @thomschumacher please check my UPDATE section

Comment: @thomschumacher apparently we can receive direct MS support since our team is tied to MS products. I opened a support case and an engineer will be assigned to help me resolve this issue. ill update this post of course once i get answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just played with things a little more, to make sure I understood the issue that you are facing. On the same box, still with the newest available SqlServer PowerShell module loaded - I get these results.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $Analysis_Server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $Analysis_Server.connect("AX2012R2A")
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $Analysis_Server.Databases

Name                                     State                Read-Write Mode
----                                     -----                ---------------
Demand Forecast ps                       Processed            ReadWrite
Demand Forecast Accuracy ps              Processed            ReadWrite
Demand Forecast Accuracy initial         Processed            ReadWrite
Dynamics AX ps                           Processed            ReadWrite
Demand Forecast initial                  Processed            ReadWrite
Dynamics AX initial                      Processed            ReadWrite
```

Now I traverse every database and their datasources, to display the connection string

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $Analysis_Server.Databases | ForEach-Object {$_.datasources}

Name                      Isolation     Max Connections Connection String
----                      ---------     --------------- -----------------
Dynamics Database         ReadCommitted              10 Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data
                                                        Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated
                                                        Security=SSPI;Initial
                                                        Catalog=DatabaseName_4
Dynamics Database         ReadCommitted              10 Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data
                                                        Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated
                                                        Security=SSPI;Initial
                                                        Catalog=DatabaseName_2
Dynamics Database         ReadCommitted              10 Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data
                                                        Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated
                                                        Security=SSPI;Initial
                                                        Catalog=DatabaseName_1
Dynamics Database         ReadCommitted              10 Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data
                                                        Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated
                                                        Security=SSPI;Initial
                                                        Catalog=DatabaseName_6
Dynamics Database         ReadCommitted              10 Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data
                                                        Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated
                                                        Security=SSPI;Initial
                                                        Catalog=DatabaseName_3
Dynamics Database         ReadCommitted              10 Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data
                                                        Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated
                                                        Security=SSPI;Initial
                                                        Catalog=DatabaseName_5
```

And the one-liner that just gives you the connection string and nothing else

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $Analysis_Server.Databases | ForEach-Object {$_.datasources | ForEach-Object {$_.ConnectionSt
ring}}
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName_4
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName_2
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName_1
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName_6
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName_3
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName_5
```

Could you take the time and try to install the latest SqlServer PowerShell module and see if that makes any difference for you and the problem that you are facing?

Comment: Woah...  this might make a difference!  ForEach-Object {$_.datasources | ForEach-Object {$_.ConnectionSt
ring}}.....the only issue is how could I specifically target a database? For example, like this: $database = $Analysis_Server.Databases[7]

Comment: On mobile, so bare with me. You would need to fill in a where-object in the pipeline. "....databases | where-object Name -Like "\*NAMEOFDB\*" | ForEach-Object...."

Comment: question: how can I change the connection string? This code retrieves the connection strings, but now how can I set for example the userID or password to something else?

Comment: That is the other question  Now we have this one somewhat solved - right? I will give the other question a look tomorrow evening local CET time...

Comment: fyi i am not getting anything returned back, as in no connection string is printed, when i use the where clause: $Analysis_Server.Databases | where-object Name -Like "*Database4*" | ForEach-Object {$_.datasources | ForEach-Object {$_.ConnectionString}}

Comment: woah...i think i may have just discovered something! so apparently, the compatibility level of a database might be why i was unable to get the connection string! i just modified my Like statement to include databases with compatibility level 1103 (SQL 2014) and the connection string printed! as for the databases with SQL 2017 (level 1400), the connection string was NOT printing! could this have been the whole reason behind this issue?? i am gonna try the indexing method i had posted in my original post here, and report results! UPDATE: its true! the compatibility level is the reason!

Comment: Good to know. Then you have something to work with when you have the next follow up with Microsoft :)

Comment: yes I have just updated the ticket with this detail :) now I'll wait for your help tomorrow on the other question, thanks so far!

Comment: The help as been provided already - couldn't let it go :) Go check it out!

Answer (score 1):

Not saying that I have an answer for you, but I think you can use another approach to get what you need, while waiting for Microsoft support.

I'm working on a AX 2012 demo system, that is running SQL Server 2014. It has several olap databases inside the same instance. I've edited all datasources to point to a different database, to show that we get the correct details out.

I installed the latest SQL Server PowerShell module while testing this.

```
Install-Module SqlServer -Force -Confirm:$false
Import-Module SqlServer
```

Now you should have a new PowerShell provider, that enables you to traverse the SQL Server as was it a file system

```
Get-PSProvider

Name                 Capabilities                                      Drives
----                 ------------                                      ------
Registry             ShouldProcess, Transactions                       {HKLM, HKCU}
Alias                ShouldProcess                                     {Alias}
Environment          ShouldProcess                                     {Env}
FileSystem           Filter, ShouldProcess, Credentials                {C, E, A, D...}
Function             ShouldProcess                                     {Function}
Variable             ShouldProcess                                     {Variable}
SqlServer            Credentials                                       {SQLSERVER}
Certificate          ShouldProcess                                     {Cert}
WSMan                Credentials                                       {WSMan}
```

With that in our hand, you should be able to do the following, that should produce the correct results

```
#Connect to the SSAS part of the sql server 
PS C:\Users\Administrator> cd SQLSERVER:\SQLAS

#List all local instances
PS SQLSERVER:\SQLAS> dir

Host Name
---------
AX2012R2A
HTTP_DS

#Connect to the server (local) - you should be able to type in a valid network name
PS SQLSERVER:\SQLAS> cd AX2012R2A

#List all instances on that server
PS SQLSERVER:\SQLAS\AX2012R2A> dir

Instance Name
-------------
DEFAULT
POWERPIVOT
TABULAR

#Connect to the default instance on the server you are connected to
PS SQLSERVER:\SQLAS\AX2012R2A> cd default

#List all available collections / areas
PS SQLSERVER:\SQLAS\AX2012R2A\default> dir

#Connect to the databases area
PS SQLSERVER:\SQLAS\AX2012R2A\default> cd databases

#List all databases that are available
PS SQLSERVER:\SQLAS\AX2012R2A\default\databases> dir

Name                                     State                Read-Write Mode
----                                     -----                ---------------
Demand Forecast Accuracy initial         Processed            ReadWrite
Demand Forecast Accuracy ps              Processed            ReadWrite
Demand Forecast initial                  Processed            ReadWrite
Demand Forecast ps                       Processed            ReadWrite
Dynamics AX initial                      Processed            ReadWrite
Dynamics AX ps                           Processed            ReadWrite

#Getting the same result with Get-ChildItem
PS SQLSERVER:\SQLAS\AX2012R2A\default\databases> Get-ChildItem

Name                                     State                Read-Write Mode
----                                     -----                ---------------
Demand Forecast Accuracy initial         Processed            ReadWrite
Demand Forecast Accuracy ps              Processed            ReadWrite
Demand Forecast initial                  Processed            ReadWrite
Demand Forecast ps                       Processed            ReadWrite
Dynamics AX initial                      Processed            ReadWrite
Dynamics AX ps                           Processed            ReadWrite

#Traverse all databases and show their connection string details
PS SQLSERVER:\SQLAS\AX2012R2A\default\databases> Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {$_.Datasources}

Name                      Isolation     Max Connections Connection String
----                      ---------     --------------- -----------------
Dynamics Database         ReadCommitted              10 Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data
                                                        Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated
                                                        Security=SSPI;Initial
                                                        Catalog=DatabaseName_1
Dynamics Database         ReadCommitted              10 Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data
                                                        Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated
                                                        Security=SSPI;Initial
                                                        Catalog=DatabaseName_2
Dynamics Database         ReadCommitted              10 Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data
                                                        Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated
                                                        Security=SSPI;Initial
                                                        Catalog=MicrosoftDynamicsAX
Dynamics Database         ReadCommitted              10 Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data
                                                        Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated
                                                        Security=SSPI;Initial
                                                        Catalog=DatabaseName_4
Dynamics Database         ReadCommitted              10 Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data
                                                        Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated
                                                        Security=SSPI;Initial
                                                        Catalog=DatabaseName_5
Dynamics Database         ReadCommitted              10 Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data
                                                        Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated
                                                        Security=SSPI;Initial
                                                        Catalog=DatabaseName_6

PS SQLSERVER:\sqlas\ax2012r2A\default\databases> Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {$_.Datasources | ForEach-Object {$_.Connectionstring}}
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName_1
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName_2
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName_3
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName_4
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName_5
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName_6
```

I would say that this should get you going, because you can now trust that you have the correct connection string details. I relation to your other question - this should give you all the details for the alter script that you want to produce, so you supply the entire alter statement as the SQL Server expects from you.

Comment: Can you explain to me what the point of knowing the capabilities of PSProvider with Get-PSProvider was? I didnt see anything used from it....also, I have installed the latest sql server just around 1 month ago. I wouldnt think it's the issue since I just installed it recently. Anyways back to your suggestion, I dont understand this part:  SQLSERVER:\SQLAS\AX2012R2A\default\databases> is that supposed to be getting in the analysis server? So my server is like this: server1.domain.com. how would I be able to connect to that? Am I supposed to replace SQLSERVER with it?

Comment: 1. The reason with the Get-PSProvider was to ensure you that the module was loaded and you could see the SqlServer in the list. 2. After the "cd SQLSERVER:\SQLAS", you should write "cd server1.domain.com". 3. Everything before the > tag is to show you how powershell is exposing the objects as a file tree structure. You should only care about everything that looks like a ordinary cmd like "cd xyz" and Get-ChildItem

Answer (score 0):

found this in a post here: http://www.mrtsql.com/2011/03/powershell-updating-analysis-services.html

See if this function in that post helps you out.

```
function UpdateDataSources()
{
   # Lets get our server name
   $SSASServerName="$env:ComputerName\" + $SSASInstanceName
   $MyConnection = New-Object("Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server")
   $MyConnection.Connect($SSASServerName)
   # lets return the number of data sources
   [int]$DataSourcecount=$MyConnection.Databases[$DatabaseName].DataSources.count
   for ($count=0; $count -ne $DataSourcecount;++$count)
   {
     $MyCS=$MyConnection.Databases[$DatabaseName].DataSources[$count].ConnectionString
    $NewCS=setNewValue -MyCS $MyCS -Pattern "Data Source=" -ReplaceWith $DataSourceServer

     if ($PW.Length -ne 0)
     {
        $NewCS=setNewValue -MyCS $NewCS -Pattern "Password=" -ReplaceWith $PW
     }
     if ($UserName.length -ne 0)
     {
        $NewCS=setNewValue -MyCS $NewCS -Pattern "User ID=" -ReplaceWith $UserName
     }
     $MyConnection.Databases[$DatabaseName].DataSources[$count].ConnectionString=$NewCS
     # write the change back to SSAS
     $MyConnection.Databases[$DatabaseName].DataSources[$count].update()

     write-output $NewCS
     }
}
```

Comment: so i have copied that script (from the website) in a whole new powershell file and changed the parameters to my SSAS parameters. i ran the script, refreshed connection/server on SSMS and opened it again and no changes happened to the connection string

Comment: i did find that he is passing the database name in the Databases[ ]. so i tried that in my code, i didnt get any errors nor did it get back the connection string. then i tried passing in Database8 and it returned the connection string. i am so frustrated, why is it only printing fine for Database8 (whether its passed as a name or index 0), yet its not working for any of the other DB's.....