# How can I get the Log directory?

Tags: powershell, azure-analysis-services

I have recently installed SSAS on my servers and instead of going through 24 of them, I am writing a script to get back the logDir of the servers.

[image: logDir]

I am trying to do something like this:

```
Import-Module SqlServer

$Analysis_Server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server 
$Analysis_Server.connect("$server")

$Analysis_Server.ServerProperties.LogDir
```

I am trying to find the logDir property [from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.server?view=sqlserver-2016#propriet%C3%A0) to no avail.

If I use `ServerProperties`, I get a list of all properties available like this:

> Name            : LogDir
>
> Type            :
>
> Value           : S:....
>
> DefaultValue    : \data
>
> PendingValue    : S:...
>
> RequiresRestart : True
>
> IsReadOnly      : False
>
> DisplayFlag     : True
>
> Category        : Basic
>
> Units           : Folder
>
> PropertyName    : LogDir
>
> FolderName

But if I do: `$Analysis_Server.ServerProperties.LogDir.value` or `$Analysis_Server.ServerProperties.LogDir`, it returns nothing.

### Update

This is how I plan to run through multiple servers:

```
$h = @{}
Import-Csv '$csvFile' | ForEach-Object {
    $h += @{$($_.Server -split '\s*,\s*') }
}

Import-Module SqlServer

foreach($server in $h.Keys){ 

    $result = "$server"
    Write-Host $result

   $Analysis_Server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server  
   $Analysis_Server.connect("$server") 

   $Analysis_Server.ServerProperties['LogDir'].value
}
```

This is my CSV file (I plan to use this for multiple purposes, so I only want to get the servers not databases for this case):

[image: csv]

I got back this error:

> Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.

Comment: you might try accessing it like a hash table $Analysis_Server.ServerProperties['LogDir']

Comment: @thomschumacher OMG you are a genius! i would have never though of that! i did this $Analysis_Server.ServerProperties['LogDir'].value and it returned the path as i want! now the only thing i worry is since i plan to create a hashtable that will contain all servers, how would i be able to index each server for the path value?

Comment: can you add some of what you've tried to your question?

Comment: @thomschumacher sure one moment

Comment: @thom schumacher Since you have suggested a hash for property which somehow worked, I am thinking this connectionstring property needs similar hashing, but I'm not quite sure how to tackle it. Could you please take a look at this thread, you may be able to resolve this nightmare ive been debugging to no avail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53037741/connectionstring-property-not-printing-connection-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might get you part of they way there.  I don't have an analysis server at my disposal you may have to change this up a bit till you get it right.

```
$servers=get-content c:\temp\servers.txt
$hash=new-object hashtable
$Analysis_Server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server 
foreach($s in $servers)
{      
  $Analysis_Server.connect("$s")
  $hash.add($s, $"$($Analysis_Server.ServerProperties['LogDir'])")

}
```

To see more great content on hashtables checkout this link: https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2016-11-06-powershell-hashtable-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about/

Comment: so i tried out you code and i was getting errors saying expression missing after comma in hash.add() argument. anyways turns out there was no need for hash in your version. the loop simply looped through the text file, but of course, i would prefer something like hashing a csv file as in the update i have in my post